# jquery vs jquery mobile with page transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, transition

I'm trying to make a simple page transition effect. I came across this one for jQuery Mobile:

http://labs.gourdisgood.com/hypertransition/

Is it a bad idea to use jQuery Mobile on a regular site? All I really want is this one effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any reason you could not use jQuery Mobile for a regular site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some of the [jQuery UI effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/)

If you are transitioning to a different page you can pull the content via AJAX and then display it using the effect.

If you already have the content on your page and you are just simulating a page transition then the effect should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but some thoughts:

- The sample page is really designed to clone the default behavior of iOS on a handheld device. It may not be the best UX for a desktop web site.
- The sample page only works in Safari. As such, it's likely using Safari's CSS transitions. That's great if you are targetting iOS, but not so useful for a general web page.
- The page loads jQuery Mobile, though I'm not sure it's using it specifically for the transitions. Again, they are CSS3 transitions and you could certainly handle the adding/removing of classes to trigger the animations via standard jQuery
- Technically speaking, you can certainly use jQuery Mobile on any site. The drawback would be initial load time as you're loading an additional JS file.

Answer (score 1):

Having attempted to do similar a couple months ago, I'd strongly recommend against it. Using jQuery mobile opens a whole can of worms that you probably don't want to deal with. You should try to find a similar effect for normal jQuery.